# Render AO pass issue (unwanted shadows)

Tags: rendering, render-passes, ambient-occlusion

When I render the AO pass is very weird. there are shadows that appear and the objects are more or less dark depending on their diffuse color. I don't understand what is happening since AO pass is supposed to not be influenced by lights. I mean, whatever are my settings.  Any idea? [image: weird AO pass]

Comment: After a quick test, it seems you are right and AO is independent from diffuse colors. Do you have the same issue without the *Denoise* ? Also, could we see the render with AO composited ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution :
https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-you-get-a-regular-ambient-occlussion-pass/1483304/4

I can't believe that Blender is not able to deliver proper AO pass in interior spaces by default...